# jQuery validate plugin inside a jquery UI dialog for SharePoint page application

Tags: jquery, asp.net, sharepoint, jquery-validate, jquery-ui-dialog

I create custom SharePoint page and I need validate form in dialog window. For this i use [jqueryvalidation.org](http://jqueryvalidation.org). But it doesn't work for me, I'm confused.

Have page with ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead":

```
<%@ Assembly Name="$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="asp" Namespace="System.Web.UI" Assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %>
<%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.Web.CommandUI, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="FormListItemNew.aspx.cs" Inherits="Layouts.ContenetTypes.FormListItemNew" DynamicMasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master" %>

<asp:Content ID="PageHead" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7;IE=8;IE=9;IE=10,IE=11" />

<link  type="text/css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" href="/_Layouts/ContenetTypes/css/jquery-ui.css">
<SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="ScriptLinkJQuery" runat="server" Name="/_Layouts/ContenetTypes/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" OnDemand="False" LoadAfterUI="False" /> 
<SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="ScriptLinkJQueryUI" runat="server" Name="/_Layouts/ContenetTypes/js/jquery-ui.min.js" OnDemand="False" LoadAfterUI="False" /> 
<SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="ScriptLinkJQueryValidation" runat="server" Name="/_Layouts/ContenetTypes/js/jquery.validate.min.js" OnDemand="False" LoadAfterUI="False" /> 
<SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="ScriptLinkJQueryValidationAdditional" runat="server" Name="/_Layouts/ContenetTypes/js/additional-methods.min.js" OnDemand="False" LoadAfterUI="False" /> 
<SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="ScriptLinkCustom" runat="server" Name="/_Layouts/ContenetTypes/js/Engine.script.UI.js" OnDemand="False" LoadAfterUI="True" />
```

ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderMain":

```
<asp:Content ID="Main" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
<div><input id="addNewRouteButton" type="button" value="Добавить маршрут" />/div>

<div id="dialog" title="Добавление пункта назначения" >
    <form id="dialogForm" action="" class="myClass">
            <label for="nameCountry">Страна</label>
            <input type="text" id="nameCountryID" name="nameCountry" class="required"/>
            <br/><br/>
            <label for="nameCity">Город</label>
            <input type="text" id="nameCityID" name="nameCity" class="required"/>
            <br/><br/>
            <label for="nameCompany">Организация</label>
            <input id="nameCompanyID" name="nameCompany"/>
    </form>
</div>
</asp:Content>
```

Inside Engine.script.UI.js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#dialogForm').validate({
    rules: {
        nameCountry: {
            required: true
        },
        nameCity: {
            required: true
        },
        nameCompany: {
            required: false
        }
    },
    messages: {
        nameCountry: {
            required: "Это поле обязательно для заполнения"
        },
        nameCity: {
            required: "Это поле обязательно для заполнения"
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function (form) {
        alert('form Valid');
        return false;
    },
    invalidHandler: function (event, validator) {
        alert('Form not valid');
        return false;
    }
});

$("#addNewRouteButton").click(function (e) {
    $("#dialog").dialog("open");
});

$("#dialog").dialog({
    debug: true,
    autoOpen: false,
    hide: 'clip',
    show: 'clip',
    resizable: false,
    height: 'auto',
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        "Test submit": function () {
            $('#dialogForm').valid();
            $('#dialogForm').submit();
        }
        "Отмена": function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        },
    focus: function() {
        $("#nameCountryID").focus();
    },
    open: function (type, data) {
        $(this).parent().appendTo($("#dialogForm"));
    }
});
```

Form alway return TRUE and nothing happening.
I'm trying to find the error many days, but without result. Where is my error??
Please help me!

Rendered browser html code:

```
<DIV class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content" id=dialog jQuery1102012247788649494162="86">
<FORM class=myClass id=dialogForm>
    <LABEL for=nameCountry>Страна</LABEL> 
    <INPUT name=nameCountry class="required ui-autocomplete-input" id=nameCountryID type=text autocomplete="off" jQuery1102012247788649494162="210"> 
    <BR><BR>
    <LABEL for=nameCity>Город</LABEL>
    <INPUT name=nameCity class="required email ui-autocomplete-input" id=nameCityID type=text autocomplete="off" jQuery1102012247788649494162="232">
    <BR><BR>
    <LABEL for=nameCompany>Организация</LABEL>
    <INPUT name=nameCompany id=nameCompanyID>
    <INPUT name=ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$TextBox1 class=required id=ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_TextBox1 type=text ClientIDMode="Static">
    <INPUT name=ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$btnSubmit id=ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_btnSubmit onclick='javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$btnSubmit", "", true, "", "", false, false))' type=submit value=Submit> 
</FORM>
```

Comment: JavaScript does not care about your server code or your framework.  Please only show us the relevant HTML as it's ***rendered*** in the browser.  Does the `dialogForm` element exist when you call `.validate()` on it?

Comment: Notice that you are missing a closing brace, `}`, inside your `rules` section...  the `nameCompany` item was left open.  That would even give you a JavaScript console error.  You've been using your console to check for errors, right?

Comment: Sure, elemet exist when i call .validate(). I corrected in this post, but my code fine

Comment: add rendered html code

Comment: I'm really trying to help.  However, you have not added enough relevant code to create a minimal working example.  Where is the HTML for `addNewRouteButton`?

Comment: Have you looked at your console for errors?  The code you've provided is still broken... missing more closing braces.  **I'm trying to make a jsFiddle of your code and cannot...  too many syntax errors and pieces are missing from your code.**  We cannot effectively help you if you cannot take the time to properly construct the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it will help someone.

I solver my problem. It was necessary to element  with id="dialog" wrap in element  with id="dialogForm" and get this:

```
<form id="dialogForm" action="" >
    <div id="dialogAddNewRoute" title="Добавление пункта назначения" class="CustomDialogCSS">
        <fieldset>
            <label for="nameCountry">Страна</label>
            <input type="text" id="nameCountryID" name="nameCountry" />
            <br/><br/>
            <label for="nameCity">Город</label>
            <input type="text" id="nameCityID" name="nameCity" />
            <br/><br/>
            <label for="nameCompany">Организация</label>
            <input id="nameCompanyID" name="nameCompany" />
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</form>
```

I'm confused, but this realy work for me in ASPX page on SharePoint. And my js code fine, except for minor errors, thanks for minus me reputation!

Important, need add js on load page $(document).ready(function ():

```
 $('#dialogAddNewRoute').wrap("<form id=\"dialogFormAddRoute\" action=\"\"></form>");
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery should load after the UI. LoadAfterUI="true".

On a minor note, your folder is named as 'ContenetTypes'. Not sure if that's just a localization/language thing or if it's a spelling error.

Comment: Ok, corrected load jQuery after the UI. LoadAfterUI="true". And ContenetTypes this my typo))

Answer (score 0):

After filling in some missing pieces and correcting your various syntax errors, I've got it working.

1. Missing a comma in the `.dialog()` method's `buttons` option, just after `"Test Submit"` as indicated by an error in the console log.
2. Your `buttons` option within `.dialog()` method is missing the closing brace `}` as indicated by an error in the console log.
3. Missing a button with `id` of `addNewRouteButton` in the HTML markup.  I added one just so I could get the jsFiddle working.
4. Missing the closing `div` tag, `</div>`, on the `id="dialog"` element.
5. DOM Ready event handler is missing the closing braces, `});` as indicated by an error in the console log.
6. Your `.valid()` method within "Test Submit" was causing duplicate validation so I commented it out.
7. Your "open" button defined within the `.dialog()` method seems to be trying to open/create the dialog which is already open.  This makes no sense so I commented it out.
8. There is nothing defining the `WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions` variable in your code, so it was causing console errors in the jsFiddle.  I removed it because you do not need an inline `onclick` handler in the submit button.  Simply use the `submitHandler` built into the plugin to run any code on `click`.

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/Lyt0awg3/**

Comment: Sorry my typo, but button addNewRouteButton on place top in block ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderMain". I know how work this code, but this code dont work in my SHAREPOINT page ASP.NET. I work in VS2013 and all error i view. On load page and on load dialog form empty #dialogForm http://jsfiddle.net/Lyt0awg3/1/, but in ASP.NET alert empty

Comment: @Sashko, how are we supposed to help you when you dump a bunch of broken code here and then tell us none of those critical mistakes have anything to do with your problem?  Fix your question, fix the code in your question, and **show us an actual example of the problem**.

Comment: This HTML markup ASP.NET page contains more 1200 rows, and i dont know how place it here

Comment: @Sashko:  **DO NOT dump 1200 lines here**.  Read this page:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  ~ JavaScript does not care that you have ASP... it only cares about the **rendered code *in the browser***.

Comment: But the rendered code in browser contains 1200 lines

Comment: @Sashko, did you not fully understand my last comment?  We do not need all 1200 lines to see the problem and neither does your JavaScript.  **Take the time to fix your question and construct a MCVE.** ***PLEASE READ THIS -->>***  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve